# Fast Algorithm for Multiple Projections in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, time-complexity, projection

My problem is that of performing many low-dimension projections quickly *in Matlab*. I have an array `z` which has dimensions `(n,L,d)`; these parameters are obtained as follows. I take an input array of size N, say `N = [200, 200]`, and `n = prod(N) = 200*200 = 40,000` and `d = numel(N) = 2`; that is, n is the number of points in my discretisation grid and d is the dimension of the input array (eg image, or plane from height map). I then discretise possible heights (that my program will output - note height map mention above) with L points, say `L = 32`.

For each `i = 1:n` and `j = 1:L`, I want to project the vector `z(i,j,:)` onto the unit ball.* At the moment, I have the following naive code:

```
z = reshape(z,[n,L,d]); z_norms = norms(z,2,3);
for i = 1:n
for j = 1:L
    z(i,j,:) = z(i,j,:)/max(1,z_norms(i,j));
end
end
```

The function `norms(v,p,dim)` takes the p norm of the matrix v along the dimension dim (in this case outputting an `(n,L)` matrix).

I have various ideas for how this could be improved. One idea was the following:

```
for i = 1:n
for j = 1:L
normsquared = sum(z(i,j,:).^2)
if normsquared > 1
    z(i,j,:) = z(i,j,:)/sqrt(normsquared)
end
end
end
```

Note that normsquared is overwritten each time, so it's not taking up my space. When I used this on another problem, it sped up the process quite a lot; however, I have just tested it on this problem, and it is actually substantially worse - about three times slower; in fact, it takes about two and a half times as long to calculate `normsquared` as it does to do the projection in the first case!

Weirdly, if I change `sum(z(i,j,:).^2)` into `z(i,j,1)^2 + z(i,j,2)^2` (in a case using d = 2), then it's actually slightly faster than the first (naive) method... if someone could explain this to me too, then that'd be great!

If anyone has any advice for how to speed this up, then I'd be most appreciative! Currently about 90% of my program's run time is spent on this!

---

*Actually, I want to project it onto lambda times the unit ball where lambda is another parameter, but this is unlikely to make a difference in the algorithm - just divide z by lambda, do the projection and then multiply by lambda, *for example*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use `parfor` when you can rewrite your double `for` loop using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to "vectorize" the operation:

```
z = bsxfun(@rdivide,z,max(1,z_norms))
```

The `max` function vectorizes the thresholding of the the n-by-L `z_norms` matrix such that all values are less than or equal to one. `z` is a 3-dimensional n-by-L-by-d array. `bsxfun` virtually replicates the lower dimension `z_norms` matrix `d` times across the third dimension of `z` such that element-wise division ([`rdivide`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html)) of the two can be performed. The result is an n-by-L-by-d array.

After [profiling](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html) your code, rewriting loops to take advantage of Matlab's [vectorization](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) capabilities should be one of the first things you try to [improve performance](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/techniques-for-improving-performance.html).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that is what I usually do. I tend to write the code in a naive format first of all, just making sure that it all works, then go back vectorise for-loops. For example, I had "for j=1:L, sum = sum + Gamma(j)*u(:,j), end", so I changed that into u*Gamma' (Gamma was (1,L)).

Comment: Are you able to explain a bit more what the "bsxfun" function does? I've seen it used for a couple of other things before - I think it was vectorising the multiplication of columns of a matrix by a vector componentwise, or something like that.

Comment: Also, I think you mean "@rdivide", not "@ldivide". Matlab documentation for `bsxfun` is most unclear on this matter, but I tried it with `l` and it didn't work, but with `r` it does. Weirdly, using `bsxfun`does not give *exactly* the same result as using the loops, just a very *similar* result...

Comment: @SmileySam: Yes, [`rdivide`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html) -I've updated my answer (`bsxfun` doesn't care what function you pass it so of course that documentation would tell you anything). It's not weird that you may get results that differ slightly in the numerical sense when vectorizing -different algorithm, and ordering -that's how floating point works.

Comment: Explaining all that `bsxfun` does is probably beyond the scope of an answer here -that's what the documentation is for and there's an entire StackOverflow [tag dedicated to the function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bsxfun). But I'll try to add a few small details on what is going on in this case.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, that's really helpful. I've done a reasonable amount of Matlab coding, but mostly on small projects where it's fine to just use a loop. Also, I realise that doing things in a slightly different order will give a different result, but I was just surprised by *how* different it was; anyway, not an issue. Your comments have been most helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing your inner `for` loop with a `parfor` loop.  `parfor` allows you to run multiple iterations simultaneously on multi-core processors.

http://nl.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html

Comment: Ok, thank you. I've got a quad-core processor (so if I can speed it up eight times, then that'd be amazing!). Your saying that has given me an idea though: since I'm doing the same, fairly simple, process each time, would this be a good operation to run on my GPU? I'm only on a laptop (GeForece 750M dedicated) at the moment, but I've got a 5 yr old gaming card at home (ATi 4900, 2GBs GDDR5 RAM). Do you think this would make a lot of difference?

Comment: Also, there's no particular need for the loops to be in that order. Would it be better for me to swap the order so that I can run the n-length (n >> L) in parallel, or is it better to run the L-length one in parallel?

Comment: @SmileySam `parfor` is CPU. GPU computing requires different algorithm structure and a bit more of learning to make it work. If you run the thing in a `parpool` the for loops wont even happen in order. In general , you'd want to have just 1 for loop, so if you can compress that nested into just 1, better (hint: you can).

Comment: I tried running it with two loops: a for loops then a parfor loop. Just 'normally' (ie for-for), the program took about 20 seconds to run. After five minutes or working away, it still hadn't finished using parfor...

Comment: To combine the loops, I assume I just reshape (n,L,d) into (n*L,d), then run a (par)for loop k=1:n*L, then reshape back to (n,L,d)? (Actually, I end up outputting as a vector, so I'd just reshape straight into (n*L,d), then do the operation, then output in (n*L*d,1).)

Comment: K, I just tested some `parfor` loops.  As you discovered, it hinders performance when you have pretty simple operations within each loop iteration.  However, I did find a performance improvement when I was doing more processor intensive operations on large matrices within each iteration.  Beyond that, I've run out of ideas on how to optimize your script!  Seems like @horchler might be on a better track for advice.

Comment: Ok yeah, thank you anyway. I shall still bear this in mind for future reference, so your input has still been helpful! I guess maybe if my loop were of length d (~2) and the projection was taking norms of length n*L (~30,000), then it would be better. Even better if d = 4 (I have 4 cores).

Comment: Also, once I've got my code fully working, then I still need to play around with a certain parameter lambda. There's no real 'right' value for this, as it's more a user preference as to how you want the output. This should help if I can get it running the same thing but for multiple (say 4) values of lambda in parallel; it should speed things up greatly, so thanks very much! :)